# Why rails console not running?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm using rails ersion 6.1.1 with ruby-2.7.1
`rails s` runs correctly
But when I'm tring to run `rails c` geeting error:
warning: parser/current is loading parser/ruby27, which recognizes
warning: 2.7.2-compliant syntax, but you are running 2.7.1.
warning: please see https://github.com/whitequark/parser#compatibility-with-ruby-mri.

Comment: Can you please explain what your issue or concern is? What you posted is simply a warning and should not stop `rails c` from running. The link provided offers an excellent explanation of why this warning is raised and should have no impact on any the functionality in the console, unless you plan on using the `Parser` class during your console session.